# Use simple dom to get select by name

Tags: php, html, simpledom

I'm trying to use simple dom to get an element by name

It's to crawl an old website and they only use name

```
<select name="id_items_1" required="">
    <option value="">Seleccione su talla</option>
    <option value="231085" data-talla="36" data-stock="3">36</option>
    <option value="231086" data-talla="37" data-stock="1">37</option>
</select>
```

I tried this but it returns null:

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = str_get_html($url);
$elem = $html->find('div[name=id_items_1]', 0);
var_dump($elem);
```

Is there any way to do this with simple dom?

Comment: you have to add attribute when find element. Example: `$elem = $html->find('div[name=id_items_1]', 0)->plaintext;`

Comment: @PhuDuy it didn't work, still null
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$url="http://platanitos.com/Platanitos-ZC-LUCY-161-Negro-49272"; 
$html = str_get_html($url);
$elem = $html->find('select[name=id_items_1]', 0)->plaintext;
var_dump($elem);

Comment: it should be `file_get_html($url)`

Comment: @Ghost thanks that worked but it's only retrieving the first result of the select and it has a few more options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to change to `file_get_html` and add `http://` to url

```
include('simple_html_dom.php'); 
$url="http://platanitos.com/Platanitos-ZC-LUCY-161-Negro-49272";; 
$html = file_get_html($url); 
$elem = $html->find('select[name=id_items_1]', 0)->innertext; 
var_dump($elem);
```

Comment: that's awsemoe, but it's only giving me the first option, does it does the same for you?

Comment: what result do you want?

Comment: would like this

<option value="">Seleccione su talla</option><option value="231085" data-talla="36" data-stock="3">36</option><option value="231086" data-talla="37" data-stock="1">37</option><option value="231087" data-talla="38" data-stock="3">38</option><option value="231088" data-talla="39" data-stock="2">39</option>

or either

value="231085" data-talla="36" data-stock="3"

Comment: change `plaintext` to `innertext `

Answer (score 1):

you need to call `file_get_contents` first in order to get html of remote url and then use `select[name=id_items_1] option` to find your selector:

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = str_get_html(file_get_contents($url));
$elem = $html->find('select[name=id_items_1] option', 0);
var_dump($elem);
```

Comment: Thanks marko, but it didn't work it stays looping arround